# How to publish an npm package for both node and web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

What is the right way to publish a webpack module to npm such that node users get a version with webpack config target="node" and users who want to use it in the browser get a minified version with webpack config target="web"?

My webpack config creates `lib/markdown-components.js` (target:node, unminified) and `lib/markdown-components.min.js` (target:web, minified), and a sourcemap file.

What do I put in my package.json "main"?

```
// webpack.config.js
var path = require('path');

const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var libraryName = 'markdown-components';

var webConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: libraryName + '.min.js',
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJSPlugin({})]
};


var nodeConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: libraryName + '.js',
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = [webConfig, nodeConfig];
```

Comment: this might help https://nolanlawson.com/2017/01/09/how-to-write-a-javascript-package-for-both-node-and-the-browser/

Comment: Ah - the "browser" field in package.json. That's what I was looking for. Thanks!